# comparing data for max min with a variable number of inputs C++

Tags: c++

For my CS class I am supposed to design a program that says:

Write a program that asks the user how many integers they would like to enter. You can assume they will enter a number >= 1. The program will then prompt the user to enter that many integers. After all the numbers have been entered, the program should display the largest and smallest of those numbers (no, you cannot use arrays, or any other material we haven't covered). When you run your program it should match the following format:

```
How many integers would you like to enter?
4
Please enter 4 integers.
-4
105
2
-7
min: -7
max: 105
```

I dont know how to assign the different number of user input variables their own values. 
The assignment is due on the 21st of january 2018.

any help would be appreciated.

edit: I am not allowed to use array or the conditional operator (?)

Comment: _I am supposed to design a program_ the do it.

Comment: What have you done sofar? Where are you stuck? Questions that does not show any attempt are usually frowned upon on stack overflow and even more so when it comes to homework. Please read  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: By the way, 'volatile' is not the best word here.

Comment: do you mean "with a variable number of inputs" ? `volatile` has a meaning in C++ (one that I dont understand, but I also have my doubts that it is what you mean)

Comment: *"The assignment is due on the 21st of january 2018."* - Do you really think anyone cares? This is not a homework-solver website, it's about collecting good questions.

Answer (score 3):

> assign the different number of user input variables their own values

You do not have to do this. You need only two variables: `min` and `max`. When first number is entered, assign both variables to that value. Then, after reading every next number (if any!), compare it with both those values. If that number (let's call it `current`) is greater than `max`, do `max = current`. If it is smaller than `min`, do `min = current`.

After all numbers are processed `max` and `min` will contain largest and smallest value, respectively.

---

Something like:

```
int n = 0;
int min, max;

// read number of variables from user and store it in n

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    int current;
    // read next number and store it in current

    if (i == 0) // first number
    {
        min = max = current;
    }
    else
    {
        if (current > max) max = current;
        if (current < min) min = current;
    }
}

std::cout << "Max: " << max << ", min: " << min << std::endl;
```

That code should illustrate you the general idea. Code the essential parts yourself (reading input) and that's all.

Small note: since you can assume that `n` is `>= 1`, you could move the first read outside the loop and change it to start from `i = 1` (loop will not be executed at all if user enters only one value). That will also allow you to avoid the `if (i == 0)` condition which is true only during the first run. But since that's just an exercise, I went for simplicity.